# How can I apply change on textView of main UI after getting text value from another activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to change text of textView on main UI into String that I got from another Activity.

Through editText on `activity_targetpopup.xml`, I want to change text value of `targetButton` on `activity_main.xml`.

here's my code:

## MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Context context_Main;
   public TextView target; 

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       context_Main = this;

       target = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.targetButton);

   }


   public void targetButtonClicked(View v){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "목표 버튼 눌림.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetPopupActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("data", target.getText());
       startActivity(intent);
       target.setText("변경중 ..."); 
       finish();
   }


   protected void targetChange(String result){
        target.setText(result);
       String targetTest = ((MainActivity)MainActivity.context_Main).target.getText().toString();
   }
```

## activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#FFFFFF">


   <!--    왼쪽 가이드라인-->
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
       android:id="@+id/guidelineLeft"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

   <!--    오른쪽 가이드라인-->
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
       android:id="@+id/guidelineRight"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

<!--    목표 버튼-->
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:id="@+id/topBar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       android:elevation="10dp"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       >

     <TextView
           android:id="@+id/targetButton"
           android:layout_width="378dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/green_button"
           android:backgroundTint="#EDEECD"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/exclamation_mark_red"
           android:drawablePadding="5dp"
           android:gravity="left|center"
           android:padding="10dip"
           android:text="목표가 정해지지 않았어요!"
           android:textSize="20dp"
           android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:onClick="targetButtonClicked"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.771" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[activity_main.xml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIfy5.png)

## TargetPopupActivity.class

```
 public class TargetPopupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Context context_TargetPopup;

   public EditText editText;

   private Button saveButton;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_targetpopup);

//        기존에 설정된 목표 값을 팝업창 힌트로 불러오기
       editText = findViewById((R.id.targetBox));

       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
       editText.setText(data);

       saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
       saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
                //        Toast.makeText(TargetPopupActivity.this, "저장 버튼 눌림.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Intent intent = new Intent(TargetPopupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
               editText = findViewById((R.id.targetBox));

               if (editText.getText().length() == 0) { // 목표설정란이 비어있는지 확인하기.
                   Toast.makeText(TargetPopupActivity.this, "목표가 설정되지 않았어요!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
                else {
                    if( ((MainActivity)MainActivity.context_Main).target.getText().toString() != editText.getText().toString()){ // 기존의 목표와 값이 다르다면 값을 변경함.
                       String result = editText.getText().toString();
                       ((MainActivity)MainActivity.context_Main).targetChange(result);
//                        ((MainActivity)MainActivity.context_Main).target.setText(result);
//                        String targetTest = ((MainActivity)MainActivity.context_Main).target.getText().toString();
//                        Toast.makeText(TargetPopupActivity.this, targetTest, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        Toast.makeText(TargetPopupActivity.this, targetTest, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       finish();
                   }

                    else {
                        startActivity(intent);
                       finish();
                   }

                    startActivity(intent);
                   finish();
               }
            }
        });


   }




    public void cancelButtonClicked(View v){
        Toast.makeText(TargetPopupActivity.this, "취소 버튼 눌림.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       finish();
   }
}
```

## activity_targetpopup.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="350dp"
   android:layout_height="350dp"
   android:background="#eeeeee"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_gravity="center">

 <TextView
       android:id="@+id/myTarget"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:text="나의 목표"
       android:textColor="@color/black"
       android:textSize="30dp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTarget">

       <!--목표 작성하는 텍스트 박스-->
       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/targetBox"
           android:layout_width="300dp"
           android:layout_height="48dp"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/baseline_check_24"
           android:drawablePadding="8dp"
           android:hint="용돈사용 목표를 적어주세요"
           android:textColorHint="#5F5F5F"
           android:textColor="@color/black"
           android:textStyle="normal"
           android:padding="8dp"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     <TextView
           android:id="@+id/info1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:text="* 용돈 관리 목표를 적어보아요!"
           android:textColor="#5F5F5F"
           android:textSize="16dp"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/targetBox" />
     <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="* 목표는 용돈기입장 페이지 위에 표시돼요"
           android:textSize="16dp"
           android:textColor="#5F5F5F"
           android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info1"/>
"
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 <Button
       android:id="@+id/saveButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
       android:background="@drawable/round_button"
       android:backgroundTint="#88BDA5"
       android:text="저장"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

 <Button
       android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
       android:background="@drawable/round_button"
       android:backgroundTint="#CDCDCD"
       android:onClick="cancelButtonClicked"
       android:text="취소"
       android:textSize="20dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.485"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/saveButton" />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPctx.png)

I found that to apply change, I need to refresh `mainActivity.class` after apply it on `TargetPopupActivity.class`, but I couldn't understand what should I do.

Using `setText()` on `MainActivity.class` was well functioned while doing it pn `TargetActivity.class` doesn't. at least, I understood how to use `setText()`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text of a TextView in Android by using the setText() method. Here’s an example of how to change the text of a TextView in the main UI into a string that you got from another Activity:

```
// In your main Activity
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
textView.setText(text);
```

Here, textView is the TextView that you want to change the text of. getIntent() retrieves the Intent that started this Activity, and getStringExtra() retrieves the String that was passed to this Activity with the key "text". Finally, setText() sets the text of textView to text.

Comment: which class in the MainActicity.class should I put this code? I put it in onResume() class but It doesn't work.